# Splitting line into equal area segments and assigning sequential value from start to end

Tags: arcgis-desktop, line

I have a line file that I would like to divide into 1-km segments and assign each segment a sequential value from the beginning of the line (1) to the end (total number of 1-km sections. I found someway of doing this in another program (FME), but I am wondering if there is a way of doing this in ArcGIS or possibly R.

In Arc, I have been working with the COGO proportion tool. This does a nice job of splitting the line into segments, but I can't figure out how to assign these new segments the sequential values from start to end.

Comment: What does 'area' mean in this question?

Comment: I suspect that you meant to put "equal length" into your title.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question that you can use to revise it.